# Allow only Printing in itext Pdf

Tags: java, security, itext

I am converting text files to pdf using itext and encrypting them with a password like this:

```
writer.setEncryption(PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, finalpass, finalpass, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
```

But the other Properties are enabled

[image]

I need only printing allowed and the others Not allowed

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I have attached a screen shot. You want the entire File?

Comment: Yes. To inspect what actually is inside. Alternatively provide a [complete short example](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around for a while I came up with the Solution to my own Problem and thought I should share it so that if anyone ever experiences the same Problem can use this as reference:

My Line:

```
writer.setEncryption(PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, finalpass, finalpass, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
```

is actually the Problem.

The Owner Password and the User Password is the same so, when the user enters password, the Pdf documents accepts him/her as the owner too as both passwords are the same. I overcame this Problem by changing the Second Password Like this:

```
writer.setEncryption(PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, finalpass, "TheOwnerPassword", PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
```

So when the use enters his password, the Pdf Document opens but he has access only to the Printing Properties and the others are Disabled.

Thank you to those who tried to help. Your ideas were useful.